# Extract numeric value from div - assign to div ID

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<span class="namedSpan">( 291640 ) New Account </span>
```

I would like to have it rendered in the following format

```
<span class="namedSpan" id="div_291640"">( 291640 ) New Account</span>
```

I have been able to get part of it working with the title

```
$(".namedSpan").attr("title",$(".namedSpan").html());
```

but that doesn't really solve the problem for me. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can't understand, you want to generate the `id` or the `title` attribute?

Comment: i needed it to generate the ID. As part of my testing I tried it with the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should really be a server-side task, but if you *have* to use javascript, you would need to use a regular expression to find the value, and if you have more than one element with the specified class, you could use the overload of `attr()` that accepts a function. Here's one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/DK9sc/

```
$('.namedSpan').attr('id', function(index, attr) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'div_' + $(this).text().replace(/\( (\d+) \).+/, '$1'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var regex = /\d+/;
var text = $(".namedSpan").text();
var number = text.match(regex)[0];
$(".namedSpan").attr("id", number);
```

If you have more than one class of `namedSpan` you'll have to specify which one to target of course.

Comment: tymeJV - Thanks so much for your quick response. The only issue with the code was that it assigned the div as id=291640 instead of id=div_291640 ... other than that it worked perfectly.